# Why doesn't Visual Studio's intellisense work for derived classes?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, oop, inheritance

Here is an example of the code that I'm working with:

```
    BaseClass class1;
    if (userControl.Key == 100)
    {
        class1 = new DerivedClass1();

        //This does not work, but it seems like it should
        class1.PropertyInDerivedClass1 = 7

        //This does work, but why should I have to cast something that I just instantiated?
        ((DerivedClass1)class1).PropertyInDerivedClass1 = 7;
    }
    else
        class1 = new DerivedClass2();
```

Is there anything that I can do to be able to more easily access properties and methods within derived classes?

Comment: As per the response from @DaveShaw Reserved Keywords for C#   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx

Comment: Yes, you can. You can use variables of the type of the derived class.

Comment: What you're asking for would require some sort of data-flow analysis to insert casts to what the compiler can determine is the current value assigned to a variable, as well as make the language more complicated. This sounds like effort no language designer will go to when you can just have a local variable of the derived type in the `if` block.

Comment: This isn't an Intellisense/IDE question; this is a question about the interaction of static typing and runtime polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to use variables of the derived class, you need to address them using a reference with that specific type.

```
BaseClass obj1; 
DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass(); 
dc.DerivedPropertyToAccess = value; 
obj1 = dc;
```

To summarize, the bug in your example code was to access the properties using a reference with the base class type instead of derived class.

Answer (score 12):

1. Pick a random person. Make them eat a sword.
2. Pick a random sword-swallower. Make them eat a sword.

The second results in entertainment for all. The first in blood, lawsuits and eventual incarceration.

Now of course, a random person could be a sword swallower, but if you don't know they are then you can't safely get them to eat a sword. The compiler won't make instances of class `Person` eat swords unless it deals with them through `SwordSwallower` references.

Comment: @Rotem I'm not sure about the comparative cost of junior developers to junior sword-swallowers in the current economic climate though. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is because your trying to access properties of `DerivedClass1` on `BaseClass`, but they don't exist on that class. Just because the object stored in the variable `class1` *is* of the type containing the properties, it doesn't mean you can access those properties directly. The only way to access them that way, is to specify that `class1` is `DerivedClass1`. So either you have to cast it, or do something like:

```
BaseClass class1;
if (userControl.Key == 100)
{
    DerivedClass1 dClass1 = new DerivedClass1();

    // This will now work
    dClass1.PropertyInDerivedClass1 = 7;

    class1 = dClass1;
}
else
    class1 = new DerivedClass2();
```

Answer (score 2):

the C# intellisense uses the same* static analysis as the compiler

your line of code:

```
class1.PropertyInDerivedClass1 = 7
```

Doesn't give you intellisense, because it doesn't work. That's not valid C#, because the compile time type of class1 is `BaseClass` and it doesn't have that property.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a temporary variable of the derived type:

```
BaseClass baseObj;
if (…) 
{
    var derivedObj = new DerivedClass1();
    baseObj = derivedObj;
    derivedObj.DerivedProperty1 = "foo";
} 
else 
{
    // Rinse, lather, repeat
}
```

Or, in your specific example, you can use an object initialiser:

```
BaseClass baseObj;
if (…)
{
    baseObj = new DerivedClass1 {
        DerivedProperty1 = "foo"
    }
} // etc…
```

Answer (score 1):

Auto-complete will not populate with derived class members, because class1 is a variable of type BaseClass. It has no idea that you're actually creating and assigning a derived type that is being stored in a reference to a BaseClass object.

I would recommend creating a new local copy to the derived type, assigning it to your original variable of type BaseClass but using the local copy to make your derived only function calls.

```
BaseClass class1;
if (userControl.Key == 100)
{
    var derivedObject = new DerivedClass1();
    class1 = derivedObject;

    //This will now work
    derivedObject.PropertyInDerivedClass1 = 7
}
else
    class1 = new DerivedClass2();
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this scenario:

```
// This decides what derived class to return depending on parameters you pass in
FunkyBase funky = FunkyFactory.Create("A");
```

If the compiler did some analysis to determine that `funky` is always `FunkyDerivedA` based on what you pass in, then the two pieces of code are tightly coupled.  This code is saying "I know this is `FunkyBase` or something derived from it, *but that's all I know*, so don't give me any options that aren't on that base class".  If Visual Studio and the .NET compiler helpfully gives you all the methods and properties on `FunkyDerivedA`, then you might do this:

```
public class FunkyDerivedA : FunkyBase
{ 
   public SomeProperty { get; set; } 
}

///// SNIP /////

FunkyBase funky = FunkyFactory.Create("A");  
funky.SomeProperty = 7;
```

And then everything works because that's the actual object you're using. But then one fine day something changes and you want to switch to `FunkyDerivedB`, forgetting that this property doesn't exist on that class.

```
public class FunkyDerivedA : FunkyBase
{ 
   public SomeProperty { get; set; } 
}

// notice it doesn't have the same property
public class FunkyDerivedB : FunkyBase
{ 
}

///// SNIP /////

// Danger, Will Robinson!
FunkyBase funky = FunkyFactory.Create("B");  
funky.SomeProperty = 7;
```

At that point things can fail in very non-obvious ways. Casting is your signal that you know what you're doing.  It's a reminder to you or anyone who maintains your code that you are making assumptions about the type of the object that you're getting (in this case from a factory method) and care should be taken when changing this code.

Now, that doesn't mean that C# *can't* do what you're asking.  It can to some extent.

From .NET v3.0, the `var` keyword (see [the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) allows you to forego declaring the type:

```
var funky = new FunkyDerivedA();
```

Intellisense and compile-time type checking work, it just figures out what the type is based on the return type of the method. Note that in my factory example above, if the `Create` method just returns the base class, then that'll be the type.  It won't cast it to a more derived class based on analysis of the call tree or anything like that.

From .NET v4.0, you can use the `dynamic` (see [the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)) keyword, which gives up compile-time type checking in favour of letting you do what you want.  Of course, if you get it wrong you'll get a runtime exception (not a compile time error) because it's resolved at run-time, not compile-time. Similarly, Intellisense doesn't work so it's up to you to make sure you know what the object is and what members are available.

Also note that, like casting, the `dynamic` keyword is also a signal that you know what you're doing and take responsibility for anything that's not right.

Hope that helps